# EDIT Download PDF file symfony

Tags: symfony, download, private

I follow this documentation https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/controller/upload_file.html

I can upload a pdf file in symfony 5 in a private directory (var/uploads/brochures/).
Information i use wampserver in php 8.1.
But i'm not be able to edit this file in a blank tab browser.
Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed this part.

[image]

Don't forget you stored your PDF in a private folder. You can't get it with the asset function.

Comment: I receive this error when i use your remark :

Comment: i receive this error : 
No route found for "GET https://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/brochures/C:/wamp64/www/untitled/var/uploads/brochures/Bouyguestelecom-Facture-20200920-62fb78fb6b154.pdf" (from "https://127.0.0.1:8000/product/list")

Comment: Again: you can't use the asset function in your twig because your document is in a private folder.
`<a href="{{ asset('uploads/brochures/' ~ product.brochureFilename) }}">`
You have to create un custom route who will return the document

Comment: I don't use the asset and I create the route. Like I say now it's totaly functionnal like I do in the self answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to SuperBob and I found the solution:  I modify services.yaml. like this:[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I add a route to list all products :[![enter image description here][2]][2]
In my view I loop on products and I create a route to download the PDF file :[![enter image description here][3]][3]
Before adding the route I modify Product entity like this :
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
And finaly I add my download route :
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

I hope this solution can help someone !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXXm7.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g6ME.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9AQx.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVBPp.jpg
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR1Mu.jpg

Comment: Please, format your answer with the help of [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, do not post your code in the form of pictures, it is always preferable to use `code blocks` (see how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)).